# How can I get my points to connect in a plot and show a trend with NA values in data?

Tags: r, plot, trend

I have a basic set of data, where I measure concentration over time for 24 months. 
Some months have not been sampled, so there are 6 `NA` values in my list.

The `na.omit()` function removes my `NA` values and gives me the graph I am looking for, but it ruins my axis.

---

(1)

```
 plot(time, pt, type="o", pch=16, col="blue", 
    xlab="Time (months) relative to implant", ylab="Concentration (ng/ml)", 
    main="Concentration Overtime", 
    xaxt='n')
    axis(1, at=seq(-1, 24, by=1))
```

(2)

```
 plot(na.omit(pt), type="o", pch=16, col="blue", xlab="Time (months) relative 
        to implant", ylab="Concentration (ng/ml)", 
        main="Concentration Overtime", 
        xaxt='n')
        axis(1, at=seq(-1, 24, by=1))
```

---

My graph looks like this

> Plot 1

[image: output]

> Plot 2

[image: output]

Comment: Many times when R skips labels on an axis (like your x-axis) there just was not enough room to print the labels.  Try stretching the window a bit horizontally.,

Comment: There are no gaps in the plotted data, perhaps it would help us if you posted a sample of your data? If it is not large, please edit your question and include the output from `dput(data.frame(time,pt))`.

Comment: Thanks! I know about the stretching - and when I do so, its only from 1-18. Because my data is of 26 values, 8 of which NA. So although the graph looks right, it is not.

Comment: Then perhaps you should add `xlim=c(1,26)`

Comment: I dont want an axis of 1-18. I want an axis of -1-24. I have 18 values, and 8 NA

Comment: I have edited my post to show both graphs. I think it'll make more sense now.

Comment: next time maybe better always to add the original or minimal data, so that one can work with it ;) -  think I achieved what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Using data from Gwang-Jin Kim's answer and the suggestion of dashing the lines where `NA`s exist, here's a redo. I'll keep the previous answer below.

`lines` (and therefore `plot(..., type="l")`) requires that `lty` be the same for all components, so to get dashed sections you need to use `segments` over each point-to-point.

For extra credit, I'm including red dots along the x-axis where data was dropped at the time the `NA` value exists.

```r
df <- data.frame(time=c(-1, 0, 1:24),
                 pt=c(7.0, 6.9, NA, 5.5, 5, 3, 14, NA, 23, NA, 14.5, 7, 9, NA,
                      11, 8, 5.2, 5.3, NA, 5, 3, NA, 1.5, NA, NA, 2))
len <- nrow(df)
notna <- !is.na(df$pt)
df$dashes <- c(TRUE, !notna[-len])
df0 <- df[notna,]
len0 <- nrow(df0)

plot(pt ~ time, data=df0,
     type="p", pch=16, col="blue", 
     xlab="Time (months) relative to implant", ylab="Concentration (ng/ml)", 
     main="Concentration Overtime", 
     xaxt='n')
points(df$time, par('usr')[3] * is.na(df$pt), pch = 16, col = "red")
ign <- Map(segments, df0$time[-len0], df0$pt[-len0],
           df0$time[-1], df0$pt[-1],
           1, 1+df0$dashes[-1])
axis(1, at=seq(-1, 24, by=1))
```

[image: plot]

---

Here's a guess:

```
notna <- !is.na(pt)
plot(time[notna], pt[notna], type="o", pch=16, col="blue", 
    xlab="Time (months) relative to implant", ylab="Concentration (ng/ml)", 
    main="Concentration Overtime", 
    xaxt='n')
    axis(1, at=seq(-1, 24, by=1))
```

One problem in your second code

```
plot(na.omit(pt), ...)
```

is that you have not included `time`, so R naturally fills in with `seq_along(na.omit(pt))` (almost the same as `1:length(na.omit(pt))`), which for you is losing your `time` data. By using `[notna]` to subset both vectors, we are preserving the data you need for the plot.

Comment: Hey it worked thanks! I wonder if i can just change (x) because each time I have to rename notna, although all my subsets have NA values and I'm plotting a number of graphs. 
This is what I mean 
` notna<-!is.na(pt.a)
     plot(time[notna], pt.a[not.a])
     par(new=TRUE)
     not.na<-is.na(pt.b)
     plot(time[not.na], pt.b[not.na]) `

Comment: I don't see a problem. Either reuse `notna` each time (as long as you calculate it for each dataset) or use a different name each time, e.g., `pt_notna <- !is.na(pt)` and `pta_notna <- !is.na(pta)`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(time=c(-1, 0, 1:24),
pt=c(7.0, 6.9, NA, 5.5, 5, 3, 14, NA, 23, NA, 14.5, 7, 9, NA, 11, 8, 5.2, 5.3, NA, 5, 3, NA, 1.5, NA, NA, 2))

png("test.png")
plot(pt~time, type="o", data=na.omit(data.frame(df)),
     pch=16, col="blue",
     xlab="Time (months) relative to implant",
     ylab="Concentration (ng/ml)",
     main="Concentration Overtime",
     xlim=c(-1, 24),
     xaxt='n')
axis(1, at=seq(-1, 24, by=1))
dev.off()
```

[image: output]

Comment: Your data has `NA`s in both `time` and `pt`, I believe the OP is suggesting that only `pt` has `NA`s.

Comment: How can I change the lty of the NA values to lty=2?

Comment: @MarieroseM.Mina: give into `plot` function arguments `lty=2` ... `plot(..., lty=2)` where `...` is everything listed above inside plot function call.